# Use scrollview and pageconrol?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, swift, uipagecontrol

In **Swift**, I created a scroll view, it works. It is horizontal, and it is for a "tutorial" page. Objects appear on it fine. It scrolls fine. It has pages. But, I want the pages to show the current page on a `UIPageControl`. This is my entire code. Currently, The page control only works when I swipe a certain direction on the page control on the view. It changes it then. It does **not** move the objects on the screen. The scroll view does scroll, but doesn't change the UIPageControl.

**Code:**

```
var tutorialScrollView = UIScrollView()
var pageCounterForScrollView = UIPageControl()
tutorialScrollView.pagingEnabled = true
tutorialScrollView.bounces = true
tutorialScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)
tutorialScrollView.userInteractionEnabled = true
tutorialScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1280, 568)
tutorialScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false

pageCounterForScrollView.numberOfPages = 3
pageCounterForScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 100)
pageCounterForScrollView.center = CGPointMake(160, 528)
self.view.addSubview(scrollViewBGView)
self.view.addSubview(tutorialScrollView)
self.view.addSubview(pageCounterForScrollView)
self.tutorialScrollView.addSubview(reactFastSVLabel)
self.tutorialScrollView.addSubview(changingDotSVView)
self.tutorialScrollView.addSubview(learnPlaySVLabel)
self.tutorialScrollView.addSubview(simpleSVLabel)
self.tutorialScrollView.addSubview(oneColorSVImageView)
self.tutorialScrollView.addSubview(justDoThisSVLabel)

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var newOffset: CGFloat = tutorialScrollView.contentOffset.x
    var newPage = Int(newOffset/tutorialScrollView.frame.size.width)
    pageCounterForScrollView.currentPage = newPage
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not done this in swift but i have done it in Objective - C

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView
{
CGFloat pageWidth = self.horizontalMenu.bounds.size.width ;
     float fractionalPage = self.horizontalMenu.contentOffset.x / pageWidth ;
NSInteger nearestNumber = lround(fractionalPage) ;

if (self.pageControl.currentPage != nearestNumber)
{
    self.pageControl.currentPage = nearestNumber ;
    NSLog(@"%d",nearestNumber);
    // if we are dragging, we want to update the page control directly during the drag
    if (self.horizontalMenu.dragging)
        [self.pageControl updateCurrentPageDisplay] ;
}
}
```